# How can I rotate Figure caption to fit under rotated figure?

Tags: floats, captions, rotating

I wish to put the caption of a rotated figure underneath the figure, rather than at the bottom of the page.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,titlesec}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{1.2ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[angle=270,scale=0.6]{figure.eps}
    \caption{text here}
    \label{fig:}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

thanks!
Michael

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've taken the liberty of adding a couple of instructions -- specifically, `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{array,ragged2e,titlesec}` -- to make your code compilable.

Answer (score 7):

Since you're loading the `rotating` package, I assume you're interested in using that package's `sidewaysfigure` environment. This environment behaves very much like the regular `figure` environment, except that it's rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise (at least when used in a "standard" setup of the `article` document class). Note also that there can be only one `sidewaysfigure` per page; however, each `sidewaysfigure` could contain several images, each with its own `\caption` and `\label`.

Here's a modified form of your code; the main modification is the replacement of `figure` with `sidewaysfigure`. You'll see I've also commented out most of the preamble code as it's not relevant for the issue at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating}

%% Commented out the rest of the preamble ...

%\usepackage{array,ragged2e,titlesec}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
%\titleformat{\section}
%  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
%  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
%  {\z@}{1.2ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
%  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
%}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
%\makeatother
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure.eps}
    \caption{text here}
    \label{fig:a}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
Some text here

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{turn}{-90}
    \begin{minipage}{3in}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{text here}
    \label{fig:yours}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{turn}
\end{figure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-a}
    \caption{text here}
    \label{fig:mine}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

Some other things here


\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `rotatebox` macro from `graphicx`:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \begin{minipage}{3in}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{text here}
    \label{fig:yours}
    \end{minipage}
    }
\end{figure}
```